# How to align Line to Point (points from multiple layer) in arcobject using C#?

Tags: c#, arcobjects

I have 5 different point layers and one line layer.

Need to connect points (from different layers) with LINE.

I have code for only one point layer. I don't know how to get all points from different layers at a time - can anyone help me?

Note: LINE only need to move based on point coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this could be done using an [IGeometryCollection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGeometryCollection_Interface/002m000001v1000000/) and just add all your points from each layer as needed to the collection using [IFeature.ShapeCopy](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000331000000), then use that collection to provide the point geometry for each vertex on your line.